# How do I view the warning(s) after a SELECT query using the MySQL command line?

Tags: mysql

How do I view the warning(s) after a SELECT query? The result of one query is:

```
Empty set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

I am using MySQL via command line on Linux.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using the [SHOW WARNINGS syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html)

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Answer (score 6):

Type `\W` in the MySQL command line.

Comment: While useful, `\W` only enables "show warnings" after each statement, it does not do what OP asked for. </nitpick>